# Vue.set doesn't update object

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

here is a code snippet

```
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in data">
    {{value.value}} {{value.newData}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        'key1': {
          value: true
        },
        'key2': {
          value: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted: function () {
    setTimeout(() => {
      var ch = Object.assign(this.data.key1, {newData: 'text'})
      Vue.set(this.data, 'key1', ch)
    }, 3000);
  }
})
</script>
```

I expect to see

```
true text
false
```

But the DOM never updated. It works if I update already existing properties like `value`.

How can I update DOM and add new key into existing object in Vue?

Thanks.

---

As @thanksd noticed the `Vue.set(this.data.key1, 'newData', 'text')` works. During testing this approach I noticed if place
`Object.assign(this.data.key1, {newData: 'text'})` code before `Vue.set` will break the logic. It looks a bit weird at least for me but I hope it would help.

Comment: Considering reading this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Vue.set` is used as a workaround for the fact that Vue does not detect when a property is added to an object. So, it seems like you have the right idea: that the `newData` property doesn't initially exist on the `this.data.key1` object, and that you'll need to use `Vue.set` to add the property and make it reactive.

In your code, `Vue.set(this.data, 'key1', ch)` is saying set the `key1` property of `this.data` to `ch` and make it reactive, so that Vue can keep track of it. However, since the value of `ch` is just the `this.data.key1` object with a new `newData` property, Vue is still unaware that that property is getting added to the object.

What you want to do is set the value of the `newData` property on `this.data.key1`, so you would need to do that like so:

```
Vue.set(this.data.key1, 'newData', 'text');
```

---

Here's a working example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        'key1': {
          value: true
        },
        'key2': {
          value: false
        }
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      Vue.set(this.data.key1, 'newData', 'text')
    }, 3000);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in data">
    {{value.value}} {{value.newData}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. btw, ` Object.assign(this.data.key1, {newData: 'text'}) ` before ` Vue.set ` will break the flow

Comment: @AlexeySh.Use Object.assign(**{}**, this.data.key1, {newData: 'text'}) instead